# Electric shock from a frayed wire

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

Let's say it's a laptop charger not connected to a laptop, and it is frayed near the tip. I am guessing about 20Volts runs through that area. Now if a person touches a bit of plastic below the frayed area, and they receive a painful shock in the finger but not enough to throw them back, about how much percentage of that 20V would they receive? Assume the person was standing barefooted and was reasonably dry.

Comment: Your question is based on a pretty severe misunderstanding of electricity and what voltage is a measure of.  If you got sprayed by a 20 PSI water hose, how much water pressure would you receive?

Comment: that's sort of what i'm asking. Except this voltage was through the plastic case of the wire a few cm from the exposed wires

Answer (score 1):

$20V$ is not normally dangerous. You may not even feel it.

It is not the voltage that causes danger, but rather the current it generates through your body. Anything over about $10mA$ will be unpleasant, above $50mA$ it gets dangerous. The current is determined by both the voltage and the resistance of the body. That resistance depends on how you touch the wire (e.g. touching or gripping), how large and damp the area of contact is, and how well you are connected to earth (are you standing on a dry floor in rubber boots, or on bare feet in a puddle of water?) A typical contact resistance for your situation is probably well over $10k\Omega$ so the current is likely to be less than $10mA$. If, as you say, you receive a painful shock, then the voltage is either well above $20V$, or you are somehow making a very good contact with the wire.

If the wire was frayed at the mains end then you would be liable to be hit with mains voltage. In the US, 110V may not be that dangerous, but the 220-240V used in most of the world most definitely is.

More information can be found at [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/how-much-voltage-is-dangerous) on the electronics Stackexchange site.

Comment: The contact area was minimal, and it is possible that it was more than 20V since it was a dodgy dell adapter. However what I would like to know how well that voltage can be conducted through a short bit of plastic. Because according to https://www.osha.gov/SLTC/etools/construction/electrical_incidents/eleccurrent.html and some other tables it could have been anywhere from 6 to 40mA through the body

Comment: There seems to be conflicting impedance values. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_shock#Pathophysiology. 10kohm resistance seems a bit high.

Comment: Your question indicated just a simple touch with a dry finger, which would be well over 10k. I'm guessing it was more than 20V. Plastic does not conduct, so no current will flow through "a short bit of plastic".

Comment: Wow. So I somehow got a painful shock through plastic

Comment: If you were touching 240V the insulation is a lot more critical. There might be some very small holes that will let you contact the copper. Alternatively, maybe it was just static?

Comment: Could be. I dont think so though. It's be nice if there was some kind of study on getting shocked through plastic near an exposed part. Could it be 'current leakage'?